# Integrating Type Tests into Unit Tests with Typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing

I have grown very used to creating "type tests" in my Typescript projects which depend on narrow typing and I do this using the `@type-challenges/utils` type utilities. So for instance here is a test I have in one of my repos:

```
describe("example of a type test", () => {

  it("SetRemoval<TSet, TRemoval>", () => {
    type Set1 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
    type Set2 = ["bat-shit-crazy", "never mind"];

    type T1 = SetRemoval<Set1, "foo">;
    type T2 = SetRemoval<Set1, ["foo"]>;
    type T3 = SetRemoval<[...Set1, ...Set2], ["foo", "never mind"]>;    
    
    type cases = [
      Expect<Equal<T1, readonly ["bar", "baz"]>>,
      Expect<Equal<T2, readonly ["bar", "baz"]>>,
      Expect<Equal<T3, readonly ["bar", "baz", "bat-shit-crazy"]>>,
    ];
    const cases: cases = [ true, true, true ];
  });

});
```

What this type utility is not important only that you can see the "shape" of how a test of the type system can be incorporated into a traditional unit testing framework.

The great thing about this type of testing is that:

1. type errors become immediately visible in any editor which highlights type errors
2. using `tsc` over the test files can be used to ensure no type errors exist across tests

Today I use **Vitest** primarily for unit testing but before that I used Jest, Mocha, and UVU. Most of these test runners will fully ignore type errors and UVU refused to run if there was a type error anywhere in the file. Neither condition is ideal as your "type tests" are either summarized as passing or you lose a lot of test coverage (aka, all tests in a file) whenever there is a type error.

What I would **like** is the ability to simply test the type validity of a "block" of code rather than a file's. I'm sure this can be *created* and I've been known to re-create the wheel from time to time but secretly hoping that someone knows of some tooling to do this that already exists in the wild.

Comment: Are you saying you want to know the test type failures, and then still run the tests to also find the logic errors in the same test run? But if you get type errors, then you fix them, then run the tests again and you'll get the logic errors. You're just trying to not have to run the suite twice in that case?

Comment: The "ideal" case would be to test a subsection of the `it()` block for a type failure (so in my example the type **cases**) but i'd be fine if any type error in a `it()` block failed the test. I typically do block my type tests from my runtime tests but sometimes it's useful to mix them (esp when testing type guards).

Comment: So a type error in your test file outside of an `it()` block allow the test in that file to pass? That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Well the _focus_ of any test is what's inside the `it()` block and failing due to something outside it would unnecessarily reduce test coverage because all the valid and passing tests would suddenly be failing. I think it's always a good practice to include a `tsc --noEmit` run as part of CI/CD so this would capture the edge case in which your type tests pass but a type outside a `it` block is failing.

Comment: In essence this **is** what **UVU** does and I believe most other test runners allow failing at the file level due to a type problem but you're loosing all isolation and for a library which has a lot of types this can make testing much harder to quickly understand where you really are.

Comment: Note: on a whim I looked over Vitest's docs and it appears they've added this as a first class test primitive! Solves my problem I guess but must be a new feature as it wasn't there a few months ago.

https://vitest.dev/guide/testing-types.html

Comment: Note on Note: actually i'm glad to see Vitest start to try and address this but currently it does not work well.